# What's wrong with this proof of symmetry of equality?

Tags: proof-verification, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm trialling a proof verifying tool (found [here](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/)), and have tried to prove the symmetry of equality in FOL, as shown by the attached screen shot

[image]

As you can see, it comes up with an error regarding the last line.  What is wrong with this?  Am I missing something simple?  Or is this tool broken?

Comment: Proving the symmetry of identity would be something like proving ∀x∀y(x=y → y=z). This is proving that if everything is equal to everything, then everything is being equaled by everything.

Comment: The bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if the tool is broken, in the sense of not implementing Leibniz's Law properly, as the move from (3) and (4) to (5) is an unexceptional example of the application of LL.

Comment: I thought that maybe my tired eyes were missing something.  Well, I'm glad it's not me!

Comment: Do you know of any free proof verifier software that actually works and is nice and simple like this one?

Comment: The bug has been fixed. (The bug wasn't with LL but a more general problem with identity statements, so technically, this answer isn't correct, but I'm nitpicking.)

Comment: @frabjous Thanks, the quick resolution is appreciated.